# May someone help me check how to create a list?

Tags: java

guys, am doing java programing and try to make a list, but i cannnot let it work as i expected, please help me find out where is wrong.
i have create the code on BlueJ and try to make main and method in different part, but when i try to add a variable in list, it seems added but wont present correctly, and remove method will call error and shut down the whole program
one is :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Plane
{
    //Create 3 types of variables. 
    private String name;
    private int safelength;
    private short station;
    private String passengername;
    private static int seat;
    private static int age;
    private ArrayList<Passenger> Passengers;

    public Plane(String psgname, int psgseat, int psgage)
    {
        psgname = passengername;
        psgseat = seat;
        psgage = age;
        Passengers = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
    }

    public Plane(String planename, int maxlength, short astation)
    {
        name = planename;
        safelength = maxlength;
        station = astation;
    }

    public void addPassenger(Passenger Passenger)
    {
        Passengers.add(Passenger);
    }

    public void addPassenger(String passengernames, int pseat, int page)
    {
        Passengers.add(new Passenger(passengername, seat, page));
    }

    public Passenger findPassenger(String find)
    {
        for(Passenger ps : Passengers)
        {
            if(ps.getpname().contains(find))
            {
                return ps;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int numberofPassenger()
    {
        return Passengers.size();
    }

    public void removePassenger(int number)
    {
        if (number >= 0 && number <numberofPassenger())
        {
            Passengers.remove(number);
        }
    }

    public void listPassenger()
    {
        for(int index = 0; index < Passengers.size(); index++)
        {
            System.out.println(Passengers.get(index));
        }
    }



    public void setname(String n)
    {
        name = n;
    }

    public String getname()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setsafelength(int s)
    {
        safelength = s;
    }

    public int getsafelength()
    {
        return safelength;
    }

    public void setstation(short a)
    {
        station = a;
    }

    public short getstation()
    {
        return station;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String text = "System checked, " + getname() + ", you can prepare yourself at station " + getstation() + " with the maxlength of " + getsafelength() + " metres."; 
        return text;
    }    
}
```

another one is :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Passenger
{
    // private varibales of the list.
    private static String pname;
    private static int seat;
    private static int age;

    public Passenger(String passengername, int pseat, int page)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
       pname = passengername;
       seat = pseat;
       age = page;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Plane p = new Plane("Joey", 45, 26);


        String text = "Please select your option:\n" + "1.Add a passenger.\n" + "2.Find a passenger.\n" + "3.Total number of passengers.\n" + "4.Remove a passenger.\n" + "5.Print all passengers\n";;
        System.out.println(text);

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = input.nextInt();//waiting type the choice

        if(choice > 5 || choice < 0)
        {//if choice is wrong
            System.out.println("Please select a vailable option!");
        }

        while(choice <=5 && choice >= 0)
        {
            if(choice == 1)
            {
            Scanner inputname = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of passenger");
            String x = inputname.nextLine();
            Scanner inputseat = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter the number of seat.");
            int y = inputseat.nextInt();
            Scanner inputage = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter the age of passenger.");
            int z = inputage.nextInt();
            Passenger padd = new Passenger(pname, seat, age);
            p.addPassenger(padd);
            System.out.println(text);
            choice = input.nextInt();
        }
        if (choice == 2)
        {System.out.println("Please enter the name you want to find.");
            String a = input.nextLine();
            p.findPassenger(a);
            System.out.println(text);
            choice = input.nextInt();
        }
        if (choice == 3)
        {
            p.numberofPassenger();
            System.out.println(text);
            choice = input.nextInt();
        }
        if (choice == 4)
        {System.out.println("Please enter the number of list which one you want to remove.");
            int b = input.nextInt();
            p.removePassenger(b);
             System.out.println(text);
            choice = input.nextInt();
        }
        if (choice == 5)
        {System.out.println("Here are all the variables of the list.");
            p.listPassenger();
             System.out.println(text);
            choice = input.nextInt();
        }
    } 
}

   public static void setpname(String pn)
    {
        pname = pn;
    }

    public static String getpname()
    {
        return pname;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. Questions with **walls of code** generally don't get attention. Try  to narrow down the question to very specific points

Comment: Sorry but your problem is bit unclear. What did you expect and what did you actually get (error, exception, incorrect results)? Also why are private fields of `Passenger` class `static`? Do you know what static mean?

Comment: Welcome to SO. TL;DR. Is this the shortest code possible to demonstrate the problem ? Please post a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1.**

```
public void listPassenger()
    {
        for(int index = 0; index < Passengers.size(); index++)
        {
            System.out.println(Passengers.get(index));
        }
    }
```

Here you are printing the value of instance variable,not the passenger's name.To print it, do

```
 System.out.println(Passengers.get(index).getpname());
```

but this will return null,because your `pname` is static and you have never initialized its value.For this,change all yor static varibales to non-static.

**Problem 2.**

```
  Passenger padd = new Passenger(pname, seat, age);
```

you are storing passenger's `name` `seat` `age` in `x` `y` `z`variables respectively,butduring the creation of `Passenger` ,you are using `pname` `seat`  `age` variables, which are null.So here do

```
  Passenger padd = new Passenger(x, y, z);
```

At last,change every static variable and methods to non-static.

Final Solution will look like this,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Passenger
{
    // private varibales of the list.
    private  String pname;
    private  int seat;
    private  int age;

    public Passenger(String passengername, int pseat, int page)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
       pname = passengername;
       seat = pseat;
       age = page;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Plane p = new Plane("Joey", 45, 26);


        String text = "Please select your option:\n" + "1.Add a passenger.\n" + "2.Find a passenger.\n" + "3.Total number of passengers.\n" + "4.Remove a passenger.\n" + "5.Print all passengers\n";;
        System.out.println(text);

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = input.nextInt();//waiting type the choice

        if(choice > 5 || choice < 0)
        {//if choice is wrong
            System.out.println("Please select a vailable option!");
        }

        while(choice <=5 && choice >= 0)
        {
            if(choice == 1)
            {
            Scanner inputname = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of passenger");
            String x = inputname.nextLine();
            Scanner inputseat = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter the number of seat.");
            int y = inputseat.nextInt();
            Scanner inputage = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter the age of passenger.");
            int z = inputage.nextInt();
            Passenger padd = new Passenger(x, y, z);
            p.addPassenger(padd);
            System.out.println(text);
            choice = input.nextInt();
        }
        if (choice == 2)
        {System.out.println("Please enter the name you want to find.");
            String a = input.nextLine();
            p.findPassenger(a);
            System.out.println(text);
            choice = input.nextInt();
        }
        if (choice == 3)
        {
            p.numberofPassenger();
            System.out.println(text);
            choice = input.nextInt();
        }
        if (choice == 4)
        {System.out.println("Please enter the number of list which one you want to remove.");
            int b = input.nextInt();
            p.removePassenger(b);
             System.out.println(text);
            choice = input.nextInt();
        }
        if (choice == 5)
        {System.out.println("Here are all the variables of the list.");
            p.listPassenger();
             System.out.println(text);
            choice = input.nextInt();
        }
    } 
}

   public  void setpname(String pn)
    {
        pname = pn;
    }

    public  String getpname()
    {
        return pname;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i fix the code and it can provide the name now, if i want to present all the values, should i make another two get method? and my .sizi() method seems not work either.

Comment: By "present all other values" i belive you meant seats and age,then yes do so. Your 'numberofPassenger()' is working fine.you jsut missied the fact that this method return the size() of 'Passengers' list,so you need to catch that value like 'System.out.println(p.numberofPassenger())'. Also while going it, i realized that you are uusing alot of confusing variable's names like in Plane class 'addPassenger(Passenger Passenger)' both varibale and class names are same.Try ot avoid such thing and choose different meaning names.